# Two questions on kernels

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with a zero object $0$. Let $B\xrightarrow{\ \ g\ \ } C$ be an arrow with kernel $K\xrightarrow{\ \ k\ \ }B$. Two questions arose, which I were not able to answer:

(1): If $k=0$, does this imply that $g$ is a monomorphism? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

(2): Let $K'\xrightarrow{\ \ k'\ \ }B$ be another arrow. If both $k$ factors through $k'$ and $k'$ factors through $k$, does this imply that $k'$ is a kernel aswell (and therefor the two factorization arrows are mutually inverse)?

Answer (score 2):

1. No. There are more pointed categories out there than abelian categories. For instance, $\mathbf{Set}_*$, the category of pointed sets, is (unsurprisingly) a pointed category. It is easy to find a non-monomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}_*$ whose kernel is zero: for instance, the map $\{ 0, 1, 2 \} \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ that sends $0$ to $0$ and both $1$ and $2$ to $1$, with the distinguished element of both sets being $0$.
2. Given *monomorphisms* $k$ and $k'$ with the same codomain, if $k$ factors through $k'$ and $k'$ factors through $k$, then the factoring morphisms are mutually inverse. But we must know that both are monomorphisms. Again, a counterexample can be found in $\mathbf{Set}_*$.

Comment: 1: Thank you, perfect. 2: I know that $k$ is a monomorphism. If now $k=k'l$, where $K\xrightarrow{\ \ l\ \ }K'$, this implies that $l$ is a monomorphism, but not necessarily $k'$, right? But if I understand you correct, you say that $k'l$ a monomorphism implies $k'$ a monomorphism. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: Sorry, you need to assume $k'$ is a monomorphism.